# Is there a way to add new lines in files?

Tags: python

I want to create my module, But I can't put the newline switch near a variable in `file.write`. Here is my code.

```
 import itertools
 file = open(fn, "w")
 lines = input('Choose how many lines: ')
 lines = int(lines)
 for _ in itertools.repeat(None, lines):
  data = input()
  file.write(data; "n")
 file.close()
```

Is there any way to put new lines in files by `file.write`?

Comment: ```file.write(f'{data}\n')```

Comment: That is `\n`. There is a typo in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a file in "append" mode with the "a" mode instead of "w" write mode:

```
file = open(fn, "a")
```

Then, after you read in a new line, you can append it with:

```
file.write(f"{data}\n")
```

When you open a file in "w" (write) mode, the file gets emptied/overwritten before the next write. But by opening the file in "a" (append) mode, you can add additional data to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Open your file in append mode. In write mode, whenever you write in file, it overwrites everything from the start and you'll end up adding only the last data. In append mode, the file remains as it is and whatever you write will be written in the file without any changes. To open the file append mode, change "w" to "a"